# Configure standard stop words for ElasticSearch using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having trouble configuring stop words in ElasticSearch using the NEST client. Here's what my index definition looks like:

```
            var createIndexResponse = _client.CreateIndex(IndexName, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(aa => aa.Stop("pfstop", st => st.StopWords("_english_"))
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<SearchTopic>(mm => mm
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Posts)
                            .Name(n => n.FirstPost)
                            .Name(n => n.Title)
                            .SearchAnalyzer("pfstop")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

And here's my query (and yes, I'm only wanting to return the ID):

```
            var searchResponse = _client.Search<SearchTopic>(s => s
            .Source(sf => sf.Includes(i => i.Fields(f => f.Id)))
            .Query(q => q.MultiMatch(m => m.Query(searchTerm)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(x => x.Title, boost: 20)
                    .Field(x => x.FirstPost, boost: 2)
                    .Field(x => x.Posts))))
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Skip(startRow));
```

If my `searchTerm` is "Simon and Diana," I get results from any row that has "and" in it, which should be filtered out by way of the stop words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent syntax strikes again. After some experimentation, starting with including just one field in the mapping, I learned you have to split out the fields and their analyzer pairings. The correct syntax was this:

```
                .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<SearchTopic>(mm => mm
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Posts)
                            .Analyzer("pfstop")
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.FirstPost)
                            .Analyzer("pfstop")
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Title)
                            .Analyzer("pfstop")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

Comment: If it helps to remember the fluent syntax, the intention is that it _mimics_ the shape of the JSON DSL. So for mapping, each field comes under its own field type mapping method call e.g. `.Text(...)`, `.Keyword(...)`, etc